# Co-induction understanding

Tags: coalgebras

Hi,

I am studying coinduction(not induction) as part of a class on static analysis. Rummaging around the internet, I am simply not finding a clear, concise description of:

- How coinduction actually proves something(it seems that coinduction is like waving a magic  hand in the treatments I've read)
- What propositions require coinductive proof
- How to operate a coinductive proof

I have reviewed Wikipedia and [a tutorial on co-induction/co-algebras](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.1418).

My best understanding:

Coinduction is used in propositions such as:

```
f(x) = ... f(x) ...
```

Where `...` denotes "stuff here that doesn't rely on f(x)".

Then, f(x) is assumed true, and the `...` is proved. If `...` holds, then the proposition `f(x)` holds, out to and including infinity.

The treatments I've read include a *functional* function Q that takes f(x) and returns some f'(x), and somehow that makes it all better.

At an abstract level, I read that coinduction operates over a coalgebra, which is dual to induction/algebras.

This (1) seems awfully like circular reasoning and (2)seems awfully like voodoo. I suspect part of what I'm missing is a careful *and clear* description of coalgebras, plus how we jump from algebra into a coalgebra and back again. The professor declined to go into that part of the subject.

Note:
I'm not an algebraicist by study- I write software and my thesis is over low-level software operations. So this is really unfamiliar to me and I'm trying to de-jargon this into my head.

(semi-cross-posted from stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Are you familiar with Haskell? Its data types are coalgebraic (by default).

Comment: Not such that I can write it; I can follow it a bit.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an informal example of a proof by coinduction.

The *extended natural numbers* E = {0, 1, 2, ..., ∞} are the final coalgebra for the functor F(X) = 1 + X.  (If we have an F-coalgebra X, i.e. a set X with a map f : X -> 1 + X, and an element of X, what we can do is repeatedly apply f until we get the element of 1 rather than a new element of X.  Counting the number of times we got new elements of X gives us an element of E.  This is the unique F-coalgebra map X -> E.)  In Haskell we would write

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat   -- possible values are Z, S Z, S (S Z), ..., S (S (S ...))
```

We can define addition:

```
add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add Z b = b
add (S a1) b = S (add a1 b)
```

I'll prove that `add a Z = a` by coinduction.  We perform case analysis on `a`.  If `a = Z` then it follows from the first equation.  If `a = S a1` then `add a Z = add (S a1) Z = S (add a1 Z) = S a1 = a` where the next-to-last step used the coinductive hypothesis.

Why isn't that circular reasoning?  We were allowed to apply the coinductive hypothesis because we did so *inside* an application of the "constructor" `S`.  In other words, even if you didn't believe the coinductive hypothesis, you would still conclude that `add a Z` and `a` were both of the form `Z` or both of the form `S x`--in other words, `add a Z` and `a` agree for to one observation.  Using *that* statement where we used the coinductive hypothesis, you find that `add a Z` and `a` agree to two observations, etc.  Since an element of E is determined by all the finite sequences of observations we can make, it follows that `add a Z = a`.

(Note that this argument works even when `a = S (S (S ...))`!)

Exercise: Give a formal version of this argument, using the definition of E as the final F-coalgebra.

Comment: If you take the minimum solution of (Nat = Z | S Nat) then the argument by induction is (add Z Z = Z) and (add (S b) Z = S (add b Z) = S b). That is, it looks exactly the same as your argument by coinduction! Does this always happen? Often?

Answer (score 6):

This was my [attempt](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/09/proof_by_coinduction.html) to produce a proof by coinduction. A coalgebra for an endofunctor F on a category C is just an object of C, say X, together with a map, X \to FX. The best introduction to coalgebra I found was Bart Jacobs [Introduction to Coalgebra](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Jacobs/CLG/JacobsCoalgebraIntro.pdf).

Comment: I actually came across your post when googling. Unfortunately, the jargon is a bit over my head at this point. :(